# PySpark does not use Python 3 in Yarn cluster mode, even with PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ambari

I have set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 in spark-env.sh using [Ambari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ambari), and when I try 'pyspark' on the command line, it runs with Python 3.4.3. However, when I submit a job using a [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) cluster mode, it runs using Python 2.7.9. How do I make it use Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give full path of python3 like:

```
subprocess.call(['export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7'],shell=True)
```

Comment: I've set spark-env.sh with "export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4", but it's still the same. Uses python2

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***Explanation:*** In the Python driver program, SparkContext uses Py4J to launch a JVM and create a JavaSparkContext. Py4J is only used on the driver for local communication between the Python and Java SparkContext objects; large data transfers are performed through a different mechanism.

RDD transformations in Python are mapped to transformations on PythonRDD objects in Java. On remote worker machines, ***PythonRDD objects launch Python subprocesses and communicate with them using pipes, sending the user's code and the data to be processed***.

***Solution***:

Just before creating a Spark session, use the environment variables from Python just like in the below example snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("String to CSV") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: There was two completely different writing styles here. Was part of this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)? Or copied from somewhere?